# How do I iterate through instances of a class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, iteration, iterator

Is there a way to iterate over instances of a class in C#? These instances are not tracked or managed in a collection.

Comment: Marc is right that you can't do this inside the framework - I think the number of times someone would want to do this have to be quite low - is there something specific you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Nothing special. Just that the form opened can be using one of two names (based on certain characteristics of the form). Maybe that is unnecessary and I'll stick to a single form name.

Comment: If you're trying to ensure that a form is only opened once - perhaps you could use a Mutex.  You could title the Form whatever you want, and just check to see if the Mutex has already been created or not.

Comment: Is this for WinForms? If so, `Application.OpenForms` may be of use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not inside the regular framework. You would **need** to track them manually.

You can, however, do this in windbg/sos - mainly for debugging purposes (not for routine code).

Comment: Or you can use the Profiling API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188781.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to have references to them somewhere, or at least know where to look, so in identifying them you'd probably put them into a collection which you'd then iterate.

If you don't know where the references live, then you'd have to have to introduce some kind of tracking mechanism. Perhaps a static collection on the type? It would have to be implemented carefully though.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

You could conceptually have your object place a copy of itself into some well-known place (e.g. a static collection) and then use that to iterate, but then you'd have to make sure you cleared the instance out of that collection at some point or else it'll never get garbage collected.

Comment: Perhaps use `WeakReference` in the collection; but either way, I think it goes against the "These instances are not tracked or managed in a collection." in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc said,  if you want to do it in code, you would need to keep a collection of them.  If you are debugging, have a look at this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2006/01/23/516139.aspx

If you need a collection in memory of all of the object instances of a certain type, you could consider using a collection of System.WeakRef's  A weak ref is a reference that does not keep the object that it references.  This would let you keep a collection of weak-refs to the object instances you want to enumerate.  Have a look at Weakrefs in the help for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In the comment thread [on this post](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/08/17/a-gc-api-that-would-be-convenient.aspx) there is an interesting discussion and solution related to this question.