# C# Reflection: Obtain a list of references to a specific instance?

Tags: c#, reflection, reference-counting

```
public class AAA {
    public BBB fieldInstance;
}

public class BBB {
    public void Method() {
        //I would like to obtain a reference to the object(s) that
        //are pointing at this instance of BBB.
    }
}
```

Say I have a simple class structure as seen above, is there a way to obtain a list of all the objects that hold a reference to the instance of `BBB` that has `Method()` called?

```
//Example
AAA aaa = new AAA();
aaa.fieldInstance = new BBB();
aaa.fieldInstance.Method();
//Method should obtain a reference to aaa.
```

Obviously, this is a toy example since `Method()` could easily take a reference to `aaa` as a parameter. I am still interested to know if this is possible. I would assume that the garbage collector has all of this information, but I don't know how to access it.

Comment: That is completely impossible.

Comment: GC doesn't track references. It builds accessibility tree every time. Roots are static fields and currently executing methods local variables. Everything accessible from roots will survive collecting. Everything else will never be checked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate through instances of a class in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786083/how-do-i-iterate-through-instances-of-a-class-in-c)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, no. Although having the answer to one does answer the other. This is about references to an instance. The other is about references to a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik it is totally impossible without a start element.

**DANGER READING BELOW; IS HUGELY INEFFICIENT BUT DOES THE JOB**

If you on the other hand have a start element, you can use reflection to traverse all properties and fields of reference type and see if they are referencing to this, ie:

```
Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj2);
```

And then you do the same thing recursively with properties and fields of both value and reference type.

I don't have more time on my hands right now, but I can chime back in and provide some snippets if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in term of build-in .NET mechanism. See [How do I iterate through instances of a class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786083/how-do-i-iterate-through-instances-of-a-class-in-c/)

You can of course make some manual tracking (but it will be your responsibility to keep track). Simple example:

```
public static class Watch<T> where T : class {
  static IList<object> s_References = new List<object>();

  public static T Observe<T>(object referrer, T instance) {
    if (!s_References.Contains(referrer)) {
      s_References.Add(referrer);
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public static IList<object> References {
    get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<object>(s_References); }
  }
}

AAA aaa = new AAA();
aaa.fieldInstance = Watch<BBB>.Observe(aaa, new BBB());

AAA ccc = new AAA();
ccc.fieldInstance = Watch<BBB>.Observe(ccc, new BBB());

var foo = Watch<BBB>.References;
```